# XMLRequest Function

Tags: javascript

I've written a short snippet of code to replace JQuery's $.post ( to get ride of JQuery, mainly ). The function does seem to work. But, since I might be using this function in a couple of other pages, I'm just hoping to get a general review of the code.

I'm not confident the parameter formatting is done properly ( I couldn't find a lot of information on the web concerning how to pass parameters to .send( ). So if anyone sees that I have done it correctly or not, that would help.

Here's the code:

```
function FileRequest(data, successFunction) {
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status == 200)) {
      if(typeof (successFunction) == "function") successFunction(request.responseText);
    }
  }
  request.open("POST", "fileHandler.php", true);
  if(typeof (data) != "undefined") {
    var parameterNames = ["command=",
        "arg1=",
        "arg2="
    ],
      parameters = "";
    for(var i = 0; data[i] && (i < 3); i++) {
      parameters += parameterNames[i] + encodeURI(data[i]);
      if(data[i + 1]) parameters += "&";
    }
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
    request.send(parameters);
  } else request.send();
}
```

Here's an example of it's use:

```
FileRequest(["load", "Projects/test.c"], function (data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest you use a library for several reasons:

- It's abstracted a lot of cross-browser differences
- Spread the task of the code to the community. That way you focus more on the task at hand, rather than fixing some bugs.
- More event and processing support, like on errors, on complete, on success, on beforesend and others.

Anyways, moving to your code

```
function FileRequest(data, successFunction) {

  //The compiler pulls up variable and function declarations.
  //To avoid visibility confusion, we'll write them that way as well
  var parameters = '';
  var key;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    //the early return pattern is best to avoid deep indention
    //so if the request isn't complete and successful, return
    //also, always use strict comparison when possible
    if(!(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200)) return;

    if(typeof successFunction === "function") successFunction(request.responseText);
  }

  //the third parameter defaults to true so we can omit
  request.open("POST", "fileHandler.php");

  //for scalability, you should not hard-code the parameter names
  //allow the user of the API to define the data name.
  //thus we use objects, and the for-in loop

  //since we use objects, we'll have to check if it is
  //the simplest check is to check if it's not null, it's an object but not an array
  if(data && typeof data === 'object' && !(data instanceof Array)){

    for(key in data){
      //similar to early-return pattern, the early continue
      //which skips early if we the condition is met.
      //if the key isn't from the data but from prototype, we skip
      if(!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

      //append to parameters
      parameters += key + '=' + encodeURI(data[key]) + '&';

    }
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
  }

  //so we send either a blank or something
  request.send(parameters);
}

FileRequest({
    command : 'load',
    arg1 : 'Projects/test.c'
  },
  function (data){
    //when debugging, use console.log if the browser supports it
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph, that helps a lot. I agree with your points about using libraries. I usually just re-implement these functions just for practice, mainly.

Comment: I also noticed that you removed encodeURI( ) from the parameter data. I think that should still be there, if you get a chance

Comment: @TaylorFlores yup, seem to have missed that.